# Add same space after the content in Jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

In the Jqgrid table, while reducing the column width I need to have some space between the content and the border. [image]

In the Header after "c" we have some space then the border, I want to do the same for the content also. Anyone have any idea how to do this.

I tried with padding but it didnt help.

Thanks,
Sandy

Comment: The picture is very clear, but it's unclear why you not just increase the width of the corresponding "Balance" column which is much smaller as all other? Moreover the tooltips shows the full content by default. You can use `headertitles: true` to display tooltips on headers. So it's not full clear what is your real problem. Do you want just increase `padding` in the cells? What is your real problem?

Comment: Hi Oleg, In the header we have some space between the balance and the border But in the bottom circle if u see the character "0" is overlapped the border line. I want to give some space between the "0" and the border line as it is in the header.

Comment: The number in your 3rd row in the column balance has more characters than the name of the column so just make the column wider to fit it. You cant have one cell bigger than the column header..